# modling tube for 3d printing

Tags: export, 3d-printing

I'm trying to create a coupling in blender, that I can export to cura slicer program.

My problem is the slicer program fills in the center of my tube as if it is a wall.

I have tried creating it from a cylinder and just a plain circle/circles (inside and outside walls).

I exported both .obj and .stl files with the same result.

I'm uploading my file here once I post my question.

[image]

Comment: I thought you clicked "edit" to attach a .blend file.  Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there may be ways to correct non-manifold vertices in blender, the only real correction to this problem appears to be in the slicer program preparing the g-code for the printer instead of blender.

These settings corrected the problem for me (I use cura 3.6 as my slicer).

1. Set infill to 0%
2. Set top and bottom layer to 0
3. increase the wall line count (thickness) from 2 to 5

These settings created a perfect print for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your 3D printer settings and limitations for how much empty space you are permitted between structures, sometimes you will have to model in support beams in hollow areas and you will have to remove them once printed. You could print a mold and use latex and resin or print and glue together two halves.

Comment: Thanks that is more of a slicer fix. I wanted to model it in blender.  Easier ways to fix in slicer set infill to 0 set top and bottom layer to 0.  Then set wall layer to 5